# IE10 & 11 are dropping JSON response entirely if it exceeds certain size

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, internet-explorer, extjs

In my ExtJS (4.2) webapp, I'm making a REST call to which server responds with **58 MB** of JSON response (uncompressed), I have GZIP enabled and in Chrome DevTools, I can see that actual response size is only under 5 MB (and response headers is having `Content-Encoding: gzip` & `Vary: Accept-Encoding` fields present too).

Inspecting the same in IE10 shows that these two headers are missing.

[image: Response Headers missing encoding]

Also, size of response is above **58 MB** instead of compressed **5 MB**, and I debugged place where response is decoded by browser (within Success callback of Ajax call), but browser is dropping the response before JS can decode it.

There's a config in my application which can reduce the size of records that API returns (uncompressed size that is), I reduced that limit which made response size come under **12 MB** uncompressed, and that works just fine in IE (although I still can't see those to response header fields in inspector of IE and it still shows me uncompressed size of JSON in network tab).

Is there any known limitation about IE around Ajax response size, searching the web doesn't help much, a link to official Microsoft page stating such limitation would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is it should be your ajax timeout, Since IE is not supporting gzip in your case, the download is taking longer in IE compared to Chrome. Thats when i think the ajax timeout is kicking in. Try increasing the timeout and see if that was the culprit. But in general sending 58MB of data is too much, You must look for alternatives like paging or batching .

Comment: @JChap I already have the timeout set for the Ajax request, and if browser was timing out on waiting for server response, I'd see request as "cancelled" in devtools' network tab instead of response and its size.